# virtualBox, Win10 Fatal: no bootable medium found! System Halted

Tags: virtualbox, fatal-error, bootable

I am using OSX-Yosemite

I've downloaded Windows 10 ISO but when I try and use it I get an error

```
FATAL: No bootable medium found! System halted!
```

My settings are:
[image]

How to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need the iso as Controller:IDE to start the vm
[image]